# Manually setting ID when using saveAssociated in CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp

I have the following form:

```
        echo $this->Form->input('Person.name');
        echo $this->Form->input('Person.phone');
        echo $this->Form->input('Person.email');
        echo $this->Form->input('Message.0.plainmsg');
        echo $this->Form->submit('Send Message');
        echo $this->Form->end();
```

`Person` has many `Message`

I want to set up the controller so that the first time the form is filled in the `Person` and `Message` are INSERTED but the second time someone fills in the form with the SAME email address, `Person` is only UPDATED but a new `Message` is INSERTED as before.

Here's how my controller looks so far:

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        // Check to see if submitted email address is already
        // a record in Person model
        $person = $this->Person->findByEmail($this->request->data['Person']['email']);

        if ($person) {
            // Set the ID (save query will be UPDATE)
            $this->Person->id = $person['Person']['id'];
        } else {
            // Create a new record (save query will be INSERT)
            $this->Person->create();
        }

        // Save the data (will run as UPDATE or INSERT
        // depending on above
        $this->Person->save($this->request->data);
    }
```

This all works as expected: If `Person.email` already exists then `Person` is UPDATED instead of being INSERTED. This is exactly what I want.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to work `Message` into all of this.

I tried changing the save into `$this->Person->saveAssociated($this->request->data)` as demonstrated in the last example in [this section of the cake manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) but the result is that cake tries to INSERT `Person` instead of UPDATE it.

The point and purpose of what I'm trying to do here is allow users to post an unlimited number of new `Message` and always have their `Person` record updated with their current contact number (which will change on a regular basis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a method `saveMessage` in your Message Model with the parameters `$personId` and `$messageText`.
The logic of this method is saving your new message with the belonging user.

The Person ID will be hold in `$this->Person->id` after your `Person::save()` call wether your created or updated the Person.

I wouldn't use any Cake Magic in this case.

Comment: yes, you're right, this is the best way to deal with this problem. I have just implemented it like this and it makes a lot of sense.